# How much memory should be allocated to root, swap and home?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I want to create partition in ubuntu for root swap and home.... if i take, say 15GB of memory from windows disk management then how much should I assign for each of them(root,home and swap)?

Comment: With this amount I would not bother with a separate /home and use the default swap.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account you do not have so much disk space, I would assign same amount as RAM memory to swap in case you have 2 GB or more, or double if it is less. Then you can divide in half the rest for home and root partitions.